# how to fit the slider to screen height?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website. What I want to do is to fit the slider to the screen height. It shows some white spaces at bottom when viewed from different monitors. [This](http://www.folkestonewebdesign.info/milestonefresh4/) is the site I'm building. I am using the revolution slider. I want make it fit like [this](http://tgdesignerhomes.com/) one. Someone please guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div with the class `.vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid margin-bottom-100` This div is the first child of `.fullwidth`. It has a margin-bottom set on it.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px)
    .margin-bottom-100 {
        margin-bottom: 100px !important;
    }
```

You need to overwrite this.

Most importantly, all the elements with  `#rev_slider_4_1_wrapper` max-height and a fixed height of 825px are set to it inline-style (in the HTML). Also, `.tp-fullwidth-forcer` as an inline-style `max-height: 825px` set to it. Best is go in and remove all the max-height set in the inline-style.

Comment: I think you just made the changes. But you can see the white is still at the bottom. This is because you haven't remove the margin-bottom that has been applied to `.vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid margin-bottom-100`

Comment: Thanks. I removed it.

Comment: Seems to be ok now. Can you still see the white space ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change line-height in this css for different media quires

```
header.main-header .menu-wrapper .x-nav-menu > li.x-menu-item > a
{
line-height:75px;
}

header.main-header .header-customize
{
line-height:75px;
}
```